# How do I logout time-based in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I need to logout user from app if user has no reaction to app or inactive more than 5 minutes after login. the app will go to main login page.

I tried to implement the given solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602606/how-do-i-create-a-time-based-flutter-app) but not got success. Please help me how to achieve this.

My Code

```
    class AppRootState extends State<AppRoot> {
    
          Timer _rootTimer;
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            // TODO: implement initState
            super.initState();
            initializeTimer();
          }
        
          void initializeTimer() {
           
            const time = const Duration(minutes: 5);
            _rootTimer = Timer(time, () {
              logOutUser();
            });
          }
        
          void logOutUser() async {
           
             // Log out the user if they're logged in, then cancel the timer.
            // You'll have to make sure to cancel the timer if the user manually logs out
            //   and to call _initializeTimer once the user logs in
            
            _rootTimer?.cancel();
    
          }
        
          // You'll probably want to wrap this function in a debounce
        
        void _handleUserInteraction([_]) {
            if (_rootTimer != null && !_rootTimer.isActive) {
              // This means the user has been logged out
              return;
            }
        
            _rootTimer?.cancel();
            initializeTimer();
          }
        
          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Listener(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onPointerDown: _handleUserInteraction,
          onPointerMove: _handleUserInteraction,
          onPointerUp: _handleUserInteraction,
          child: MaterialApp(
    )
    );
    }
    
        }
```

I tried with Listener and GestureDetector but it's not working. User logged out even actively using the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late but might be help to someone other. Last time I faced same problem. I was surprised when I declared **Timer _rootTimer** as global variable and my code started working.

My code is:

```
Timer _rootTimer;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AppRoot();
}

class AppRoot extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  AppRootState createState() => AppRootState();
}

class AppRootState extends State<AppRoot> {
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initializeTimer();
  }
void initializeTimer() {
    if (_rootTimer != null) _rootTimer.cancel();
    const time = const Duration(minutes:  5 );
    _rootTimer = Timer(time, () {
      logOutUser();
    });
  }
void logOutUser() async {
 // Log out the user if they're logged in, then cancel the timer.
           
            
 _rootTimer?.cancel();
}

// You'll probably want to wrap this function in a debounce
  void _handleUserInteraction([_]) {
    if (_rootTimer != null && !_rootTimer.isActive) {
      // This means the user has been logged out
      return;
    }
    _rootTimer?.cancel();

    initializeTimer();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onPointerDown: _handleUserInteraction,
      onPointerMove: _handleUserInteraction,
      onPointerUp: _handleUserInteraction,
      child:MaterialApp(
          title: 'example',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: HomePage()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```